# Autofill/clear HTML Form Fields using JavaScript onchange function and checkbox state

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to add the JavaScript code needed to enable auto-fill on this form.  Whenever the checkbox is checked, the code should automatically copy the values from Shipping Name and Shipping Zip into the Billing Name and Billing Zip.  If the checkbox is unchecked, the Billing Name and Billing Zip should go blank.
Here is the HTML code:

```html
 <form>
  <label for="shippingName">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="Name" id="shippingName" required>
  <br/>
  <label for="shippingzip">Zip code:</label>
  <input type="text" name="zip" id="shippingZip" pattern=[ 0-9]{5} required>
  <br/>
 <input type="checkbox" id="same" name="same" onchange="billingFunction()" />
  <label for="same">Is the Billing Information the Same?</label>
  <label for="billingName">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="Name" id="billingName" required>
  <br/>
  <label for="billingzip">Zip code:</label>
  <input type="text" name="zip" id="billingZip" pattern=[ 0-9]{5} required>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Verify" />
 </form>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function billingFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById("same").checked) {
    document.getElementById("billingName").value = document.getElementById("shippingName").value;
    document.getElementById("billingZip").value = document.getElementById("shippingZip").value;

  }
 else {
    document.getElementById("billingName").value = "";
    document.getElementById("billingZip").value = "";
  }
}
```

Any other ideas / such as jQuery would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function billingFunction() {
if (document.getElementById("same").checked) {
        document.getElementById("billingName").value = document.getElementById("shippingName").value;
document.getElementById("billingZip").value = document.getElementById("shippingZip").value;
}
else {
  document.getElementById("billingName").value = "";
  document.getElementById("billingZip").value = "";
}
  }
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
input:focus {
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
}
fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 4%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Shipping|Billing Data</title>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>JavaScript Homework</h1>
  <p>Add the JavaScript code needed to enable auto-complete on this form. Whenever the checkbox is checked, the code should automatically copy the values from Shipping Name and Shipping Zip into the Billing Name and Billing Zip. If the checkbox is unchecked,
    the Billing Name and Billing Zip should go blank.</p>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Shipping Information</legend>
      <label for="shippingName">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="shipName" id="shippingName" required>
      <br/>
      <label for="shippingzip">Zip code:</label>
      <input type="text" name="shipZip" id="shippingZip" pattern="[0-9]{5}" required>
      <br/>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" id="same" name="same" onchange="billingFunction()" />
    <label for="same">Is the Billing Information the Same?</label>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Billing Information</legend>
      <label for="billingName">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="billName" id="billingName" required>
      <br/>
      <label for="billingzip">Zip code:</label>
      <input type="text" name="billZip" id="billingZip" pattern="[0-9]{5}" required>
      <br/>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Verify" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 $('#change_password').click(function(){
 if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
    alert("checked");
  }
else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
    alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
  }
  });
</script>
```

Try this approach. It is a code from my project.

Answer (score 0):

/*Here is the complete Javascript function. use it in your coding.

```
function billingFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById('same').checked) {
        var shippingName = document.getElementById('shippingName').value;
        var shippingZip = document.getElementById('shippingZip').value;

        document.getElementById('billingName').value = shippingName;
        document.getElementById('billingZip').value = shippingZip;

    } else {
        document.getElementById('billingName').value = "";
        document.getElementById('billingZip').value = "";
    }
}
```